# DropDownListFor Validation Always fires on edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two DropDownListFor elements on a edit view. Even though, value is selected in dropdown, it always fires the DropDownListFor required field validation When i try to submit the view.

```
 public class propertyTypeModel
        {
            public int type_id { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Property Type Required")]
            [Display(Name = "Type")]
            public string property_type { get; set; }
        }

    public class propertyStatusModel
        {
            public int status_id { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status Required")]
            [Display(Name = "Status")]
            public string property_status { get; set; }
        }

    public class propertyModel
        {

            public int id { get; set; }


            [Display(Name = "Property Type")]
            public propertyTypeModel property_type { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Property Type")]
            [Required]
            public List<propertyTypeModel> property_type_lst { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Property Status")]
            public propertyStatusModel property_status { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Property Status")]
            [Required]
            public List<propertyStatusModel> property_status_lst { get; set; }

        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
            {
                rep=new propertyRepository();
                propertyModel model = new propertyModel();
                model.id = id;

                model.property_type_lst = getPropertyTypes();//load dropdown values
                model.property_status_lst = getPropertyStatus();//load dropdown values

                return View(model);
            }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, propertyModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                model.property_type_lst = getPropertyTypes();
                model.property_status_lst = getPropertyStatus();
                model.property_owner_lst = getPropertyOwners();

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    rep = new propertyRepository();

                    rep.Update(model);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }


                return View(model);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }


    @model RealEstateApp.Models.propertyModel
    <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.property_type_lst)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.property_type.type_id, new SelectList(Model.property_type_lst, "type_id", "property_type"),"Select Below...")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.property_type_lst)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.property_status_lst)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.property_status.status_id, new SelectList(Model.property_status_lst, "status_id", "property_status"),"Select Below...") 
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.property_status_lst)
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model.property_type_lst, new SelectList(Model.property_type_lst, "type_id", "property_type"),"Select Below...", new {id = Model.property_type.type_id})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.property_type_lst)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.property_status_lst)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model.property_status_lst, new SelectList(Model.property_status_lst, "status_id", "property_status"),"Select Below...", new {id = Model.property_status.status_id}) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.property_status_lst)
</div>
```